# how to Build common Business logic for Windows app or web app in common DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, web

how to identify Windows app or web app in common DLL

I am using common method Name GetParcelCode for both windows and web application..ie.. I Build as common DLL business logic.

Previously,I am using individual Classes for both web and Windows

1) For Web I am passing DBHandler as one of the parameter for GetParcelCode method
2) For Windows I am passing Object as one of the parameter for GetParcelCode method

the above mentioned parameter for DBconnection

now I have to Build a common DLL for both web app and Windows.

When I am calling GetParcelCode method from web appliction how I Handle whether it is web or windows.

I am using VS2003 VB.Net.

Suggest me how can I go ahead..

Comment: If you're using different parameter types, it doesn't sound like you've actually got a common method after all. How do you use the parameter in each case? What is `DBHandler` in your system?

Comment: DBHandler is connection string object....

Comment: And where it that declared? And how are you using the "object" parameter in the Windows version? You really need to give us more context.